# How to change button size for iPhone4 separately?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How do I change button sizes for iPhone 4 screen size separately? The buttons fit iPhone 5 screen size perfectly ,but not the iPhone 4 screen size.So I probably need to adjust button size for the iPhone 4 separately unless I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for iphone 4 you can either use auto-resizing mask or constrants or you can detect view height and change frame of button

```
if(self.view.height == 568.0)
{
    //Set frame for iphone 5
}
else
{
    //Set frame for iphone 4
}
```